# Can ghci reoder IO actions within unsafePerformIO IO blocks

Tags: haskell, ghci

**Can IO actions in IO blocks call within `unsafePerformIO` be reordered?**

I have effectively the IO function.

```
assembleInsts :: ... -> IO S.ByteString
assembleInsts ... = do
    tmpInputFile <- generateUniqueTmpFile
    writeFile tmpInputFile str
    (ec,out,err) <- readProcessWithExitCode asm_exe [tmpInputFile] ""
    -- asm generates binary output in tmpOutputFile
    removeFile tmpInputFile
    let tmpOutputFile = replaceExtension tmpIsaFile "bits" -- assembler creates this
    bs <- S.readFile tmpOutputFile -- fails due to tmpOutputFile not existing
    removeFile tmpOutputFile
    return bs
```

where `S.ByteString` is a strict byte string.

Sadly, I need to call this in a tree of pure code far from the IO monad,
but since I the assembler behaves as a referentially transparent
(given unique files) tool, I figured for the time being I could make
an unsafe interface for the time being.

```
{-# NOINLINE assembleInstsUnsafe #-}
assembleInstsUnsafe :: ... -> S.ByteString
assembleInstsUnsafe args = unsafePerformIO (assembleInsts args)
```

In addition I added to the top of the module the following annotation
as per the documentation's (`System.IO.Unsafe`'s) instructions.

```
{-# OPTIONS -fno-cse #-}
module Gen.IsaAsm where
```

(I tried to also add `-fnofull-laziness` as well, as per a reference that
I consulted, but this was rejected by the compiler.  I don't think that
case applies here though.)

Running in `ghci` it reports the following error.

```
*** Exception: C:\Users\trbauer\AppData\Local\Temp\tempfile_13516_0.dat: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

But if I remove `removeFile tmpOutputFile`, then it magically works.
*Hence, it seems like the `removeFile` is executing ahead of the process termination.*
Is this possible?  The bytestring is strict, and I even tried to force the output at one point with a:

```
S.length bs `seq` return ()
```

before the `removeFile`.

**Is there a way to dump intermediate code to find out what's going on?**
(Maybe I can trace this with Process Monitor or something to find out.)
Unfortunately, I'd like to clean up within this operation (remove the file).

I think the exe version might work, but under ghci it fails (interpreted). 
I am using GHC 7.6.3 from the last Haskell Platform.

I know `unsafePerformIO` is a really big hammer and has other risks associated with it, but it would really limit the complexity of my software change.

Comment: My first guess is that `readProcessWithExitCode` and `S.readFile` are doing lazy I/O... though my guess is that `S` stands for `Data.ByteString.Strict`... so I'm not sure. Worth looking into though?

Comment: "`readProcessWithExitCode` creates an external process, reads its standard output and standard error strictly, waits until the process terminates, and then returns the `ExitCode` of the process, the standard output, and the standard error." http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html

Comment: Is `S` `Data.ByteString.Lazy` or `Data.ByteString.Strict`? If `S` is  `Data.ByteString.Lazy`, what is `tmpDatFile`, and how is it different than `tmpOutputFile`?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the ambiguities. `S` is a strict byte string.  `tmpDatFile` was indeed supposed to be `tmpOutputFile`.  It is created by the external process launched via `readProcessWithExitCode`.  The standard output stream is ignored and not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally my fault.... sorry everyone.  *GHC does not reorder IO actions in an IO block under the above stated conditions as mentioned by those above.*  The assembler was just failing to assemble the output and create the assumed file.  I simply forgot to check the exit code or the output stream of the assembler.  I assumed the input to be syntactically correct since it is generated, the assembler rejected it and simply failed to create the file.  It gave a valid error code and error diagnostic too, so that was really bad on my part.  I may have been using `readProcess` the first time around, which raises an exception on a non-zero exit, but must have eventually changed this.   I think the assembler had a bug where it didn't correctly indicate a failing exit code for some cases, and I had to change from  `readProcessWithExitCode`.

*I am still not sure why the error went away when I elided the `removeFile`.*

I thought about deleting the question, but I a hoping the suggestions above help others debug similar (more valid) problems as well.  I've been burned by the lazy IO thing Cirdec mentioned, and the `-ddump-simpl` flag mentioned by chi is good to know as well.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be applicable, since it is based on assumptions unspecified in your question. In particular, this answer is based on the following two assumptions. `S`, which is unspecified, is `Data.ByteString.Lazy` and `tmpDatFile`, which is undefined, is `tmpOutputFile`.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as S
...
    let tmpDatFile = tmpOutputFile
```

#### Possible Cause

If these assumptions are true, `removeFile` will run too early, even without the use of `unsafePerformIO`. The following code

```
import System.Directory
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as S

assembleInsts = do
    -- prepare a file, like asm might have generated
    let tmpOutputFile = "dataFile.txt"
    writeFile tmpOutputFile "a bit of text"
    -- read the prepared file 
    let tmpDatFile = tmpOutputFile
    bs <- S.readFile tmpOutputFile
    removeFile tmpDatFile
    return bs

main = do
    bs <- assembleInsts
    print bs
```

Results in the error

> lazyIOfail.hs: DeleteFile "dataFile.txt": permission denied (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)

Removing the line `removeFile tmpDatFile` will make this code execute correctly, just like you describe, but leaving behind the temporary file isn't what is desired.

#### Possible Solution

Changing the import `S` to

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as S
```

instead results in the correct output,

> "a bit of text".

#### Explanation

The documentation for `Data.ByteSting.Lazy`'s `readFile` states that it will

> Read an entire file lazily into a `ByteString`. The Handle will be held open until EOF is encountered.

Internally, `readfile` accomplishes this by calling `unsafeInterleaveIO`. `unsafeInterleaveIO` defers execution of the IO code until the term it returns is evaluated.

```
hGetContentsN :: Int -> Handle -> IO ByteString
hGetContentsN k h = lazyRead -- TODO close on exceptions
  where
    lazyRead = unsafeInterleaveIO loop

    loop = do
        c <- S.hGetSome h k -- only blocks if there is no data available
        if S.null c
          then do hClose h >> return Empty
          else do cs <- lazyRead
                  return (Chunk c cs)
```

Because nothing tries to look at the constructor of the `bs` defined in the example above until it is `print`ed, which doesn't happen until after `removeFile` has been executed, no chunks are read from the file (and the file is not closed) before `removeFile` is executed. Therefore, when `removeFile` is executed, the `Handle` opened by `readFile` is still open, and the file can't be removed.

Comment: For the proposed solution `S` is indeed a strict byte string.  Even so, I did try to force the output by put in a `seq` against `S.length` before removing the file.  This didn't change the result.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are using `unsafePerformIO`, IO actions should not be reordered. If you want to be sure of that, you can use the `-ddump-simpl` flag to see the intermediate Core language which GHC produces, or even one of the [other `-dump-*` flags](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-debugging.html) showing all the compilation intermediate steps up to assembly.

I am aware that this answers what you asked, and not what you actually need, but you can rule out GHC bugs at least. It seems unlikely there's a bug affecting this in GHC, though.